# Vertical Scrolling for iPhone in ActionScript 3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air-native-extension

I am working on a project for iPhone (flash builder 4.6), in which I have to implement a custom scroll component.

Basically I have to show the Facebook users in a list render-er, scrolling is working fine initially but when the number of friends increases (more than 300) the scrolling freezes (mainly tapping not working, swipe is still working, I mean to say that `MOUSE_MOVE` event is not working properly here).

If any one have any idea about it, please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create (or use an existing) list component that uses a virtual list. i.e. only creates enough cells (or renderers) needed to fill a screen. It then recycles the renderers as you scroll.

Have a look at this:
http://madskool.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/tutorial-3-lists-and-pickers/

Or if you are using stage 3D, http://feathersui.com/examples/components-explorer/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but that is bit confusing for me. Can you please tell me which component I should use.

Comment: 'List' component for both options.

Comment: Do you know about any existing list component with virtual list, which can perform this type of functionality ??

Comment: Yes, Feathers List component and MadComponents List component